# Break and wrap (widget-not Text Widget-) to next line in a row but start from extreme left of parent widget

Tags: flutter, widget

I am using Flutter, and I want to achieve this layout:

[image]

The widget cannot be `Text`; Because I want to perform a Function when the widget is Pressed. `Row` or `Column` does not work; Because I want the widget to be split/break.

And just to be clear, I want to make a page like this, where I can click on each verse:

[image]

**In this code, I take each verse, cut it into its own words, collect the words, put them in a InkWell, and then I do that with the other verses.**

```
  List<InkWell> versesList = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < versesCount!; i++) {
      versesList.add(InkWell(
        onLongPress: () {},
        child: Wrap(
            direction: Axis.horizontal,
            textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
            children:
                "${getVerse(surahNumb!, startVerse! + i, verseEndSymbol: true)}"
                    .split(" ")
                    .map((e) => InkWell(
                          onTap: () => () {},
                          child: Text(e),
                          //style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Quran", fontSize: 18),
                        ))
                    .toList()),
      ));
```

I present the list here:

```
SizedBox(
                          width: 200,
                          //height: 480,

                          child: Wrap(
                              direction: Axis.horizontal,
                              alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
                              textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                              children: quranController.versesList),
```

The result:

[image]

This what I need:
[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.